# Linux SFTP - Certificado pedindo senha

Tags: linux, sftp

Preciso acessar um servidor FTP, do qual já me enviaram um certificado chamado "empresa.cert".

No Windows, usando o WinSCP, crio uma conexão usando esse arquivo de certificado, e a conexão é feita normalmente, não sendo me pedida nenhuma senha. Mas no Linux, é me pedida uma senha. A sintaxe que estou tentando é:

```
sftp -P 58010 -i /home/joao/empresa.cert joao@xxxxxxxx.com.br
```

Onde ele pede:

> Enter passphrase for key '/home/joao/empresa.cert':

O problema não é com o certificado, pois no Windows, ele acessa sem pedir senha. Como acesso no Linux via SFTP sem que o certificado peça senha?

Comment: Peça para que te enviem a chave Privada do Certificado e utilize a seguinte flag no comando "-oIdentityFile=/your/private/key"

Comment: Erlon, tentei assim também, mas ainda pede senha: 

sftp -P 58010 -oIdentityFile=/home/joao/empresa.cert joao@xxxxxx.com.br

Comment: Seu comando ficaria o seguinte: sftp -P 58010 -i /home/joao/empresa.cert -oIdentityFile=/your/private/empresa.key joao@xxxxxxxx.com.br

Comment: Já descobri o que ocorria. O pessoal depois informou que o certificado foi gerado em PPK, mas que o cliente no Linux só aceita o certificado tipo PEM. Por isso funcionava no windows e no Linux não. Eles geraram outro e me enviaram, e agora o problema foi sanado.